# Javascript Fetch API Cors : Doesen't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I am dealing with an external api. I want to post some data so i set a token in the headers to be able to access the api.

I am told that my test origin has been whitelisted `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`

However i get the following error.

> Failed to load
>   https://external-api.com/api/transactions/ad2d7a69-f723-4798-9fa5-a95a76d65324/document:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'.

```
async submitDocument(transationId, token, base64) {

    const url = host + "/api/transactions/" + transationId + "/document"

    const body = {
        "image": base64,
    }

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('token', token);

    const request = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: headers,
        credentials: 'include'
    }

    const data = await fetch(url, request);
    const response = await data.json();

    return response;

}
```

This function call is being made browser side on the following page. `http://127.0.0.1:8081/`

**Response from server**

```
Request URL: https://externalapi.com/api/transactions/f400aaec-3fde-4458-a36e-fe03d550fc00/document
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 54.194.37.150:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 15:29:27 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Origin
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,token
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: externalapi.com
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8081/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not configured properly by the server. Could you provide the exact Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the response?

Answer (score 0):

just read the error message carefully! Your domain must not be whitelistet with '*'.

It has to be 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'. You have to ask external-api.com to recheck it.

Comment: So you are saying this function call can only be made on a specific url. The function call should only be made on http://127.0.0.1:8081/test/ and be whitelisted on http://127.0.0.1:8081/test/?

Comment: If i wanted this function call to be made on /test or /test2 the server needs to whitelist them seperatly?

Comment: externalapi.com whitelisted you with '*', which means everyone is allowed to call and use them.
But since you have credentials: include, this is not enough for you. they have to whitelist your domain.

edit: /test and /test2 doesn't matter

Comment: No they whitelisted the domain http://127.0.0.1:8081/ i mentioned that originally

Comment: Btw do i NEED "credentials: include" i think i do right because i am passing in a token into the header?

Comment: I think you need the credentials: include, yes.

Comment: can you edit your post and show the response from external-api.com?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173640/discussion-between-kay-and-schildi).

Comment: check the original post

Answer (score 0):

In your request you have credentials set in a token header and the Origin of your request is:

```
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

The request in this case will proceed only if the server answers with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

Otherwise the request is blocked by the browser
Check here for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios

In particular the section "Requests with credentials"

Comment: this Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081 is a server side problem correct? They have not configured it properly?

Comment: i should ask them to properly configure this?

Comment: Yes it's a problem on the server side.